# Set max title length - similar to excerpt length for outside of single.php

Tags: title

I've been searching for a code snippet that lets me limit the title length similar to what you can to with the_excerpt and then just display "(...)" if the title is too long.
I'd like to use that in loops outside of single.php, e.g. in my sidebar where an extremely long title would harm the layout.

All I could find was this code snippet, but that does obviously not what I want.

```
function maxWord($title)
{
global $post;
$title = $post->post_title;
if (str_word_count($title) >= 10 ) //set this to the maximum number of words
wp_die( __('Error: your post title is over the maximum word count.') );
}
add_action('publish_post', 'maxWord');
```

Is it possible at all?

I'm looking for something similar like this, just not for the excerpt, but the title:

```
function excerpt($limit) {
      $excerpt = explode(' ', get_the_excerpt(), $limit);
      if (count($excerpt)>=$limit) {
        array_pop($excerpt);
        $excerpt = implode(" ",$excerpt).'&nbsp;(...)';
      } else {
        $excerpt = implode(" ",$excerpt);
      } 
      $excerpt = preg_replace('`\[[^\]]*\]`','',$excerpt);
      return $excerpt;
    }

    function content($limit) {
      $content = explode(' ', get_the_content(), $limit);
      if (count($content)>=$limit) {
        array_pop($content);
        $content = implode(" ",$content).'&nbsp;(...)';
      } else {
        $content = implode(" ",$content);
      } 
      $content = preg_replace('/\[.+\]/','', $content);
      $content = apply_filters('the_content', $content); 
      $content = str_replace(']]>', ']]&gt;', $content);
      return $content;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends 100% on how you're getting the title.  If you're using a global object (i.e. `$post->post_title` then you're not passing it through any filters and you'll have to use some fancy post-processing to pare the title down.

However, if you're inside a post loop, use either `the_title()` to echo the current post's title or `get_the_title()` to return it programatically.

If you use one of those two functions, WordPress will automatically pass the post title through a filter before giving it back to you.

Then you can add the following to *the top* of your `sidebar.php` file:

```
function japanworm_shorten_title( $title ) {
    $newTitle = substr( $title, 0, 20 ); // Only take the first 20 characters
    
    return $newTitle . " &hellip;"; // Append the elipsis to the text (...) 
}
add_filter( 'the_title', 'japanworm_shorten_title', 10, 1 );
```

Now, every time you reference `the_title()` or `get_the_title()` in your sidebar, they will return the automatically-shortened version instead of the full version.

Just remember to remove this filter at *the end* of your `sidebar.php` file or it will apply elsewhere in your theme as well:

```
remove_filter( 'the_title', 'japanworm_shorten_title' );
```

---

## Update 10/3/2011

If you want a function you can use anywhere, I recommend making your own versions of `get_the_title()` and `the_title()` and using them in your code.  For example:

```
function japanworm_get_the_title( $length = null, $id = 0 ) {
    $post = &get_post($id);

    $title = isset($post->post_title) ? $post->post_title : '';
    $id = isset($post->ID) ? $post->ID : (int) $id;

    if ( !is_admin() ) {
        if ( !empty($post->post_password) ) {
            $protected_title_format = apply_filters('protected_title_format', __('Protected: %s'));
            $title = sprintf($protected_title_format, $title);
        } else if ( isset($post->post_status) && 'private' == $post->post_status ) {
            $private_title_format = apply_filters('private_title_format', __('Private: %s'));
            $title = sprintf($private_title_format, $title);
        }
    }

    // Shorten the title
    if ( null != $length ) {
        $length = (int) $length;

        $title = substr( $title, 0, $length ); // Only take the first 20 characters
    
        $title .= " &hellip;";
    }

    return apply_filters( 'the_title', $title, $id );
}

function japanworm_the_title($before = '', $after = '', $echo = true, $length = null) {
    $title = get_the_title($length);

    if ( strlen($title) == 0 )
        return;

    $title = $before . $title . $after;

    if ( $echo )
        echo $title;
    else
        return $title;
}
```

These are copied from the original `the_title()` and `get_the_title()` functions, so they *should* work in the loop the same way.  I haven't tested this, though.

Comment: Hello. Thank you very much. Actually I'm looking for something I can use more "freely" anywhere I like (see my updated question). I don't want to use it only in my sidebar, that was only an example. I have a similar code in my function.php for a custom excerpt where I can adjust the lenght by putting a number into "(30)" it. Is that also possible for the title?

Comment: See my edit for another option.

Comment: Hello. Sorry for the late reply. I've been off for a few days. I tried the code and put it into my function.php but got a syntax error, so it doesn't seem to work unfortunately.

Comment: That's where the "I haven't tested this though" comment comes in. what was the syntax error?  I might have had a typo.

Comment: It seems to be this line  `$title .= " &hellip;"
    }` as the error message says: "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' in /hermes/bosweb25a/b155/ipg.zoomingjapancom/wp-content/themes/alltuts/functions.php on line 51"

Comment: Should be an extra semi-colon at the end of that line (making it `$title .= " &hellip;";`).  Editing my answer ...

Comment: Okay, great, so no I don't get an error message anymore, but the function doesn't seem to work. Maybe I'm calling the title wrong. I tried: `<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title('12'); ?></a>` I tried it with and without the '' ... both times it just displays a "12" in front of the title. Any ideas? And thanks so much!

Comment: Take a second look at the code.  If you're still calling `the_title()` then you're not using the functions I wrote above.  These were meant to be *replacements* for the standard functions in WordPress that include your custom functionality.

Comment: Like this right? `<?php japanworm_the_title(2); ?>` Still the same issue. And if I try this `<?php japanworm_get_the_title(12); ?>` no title is displayed at all.

Comment: Look at the function signature: `function japanworm_get_the_title( $length = null, $id = 0 )` ... so you need to specify both the length *and* the id.  Try `japanworm_get_the_title(20, 12)` to return a 20-character title for post ID 12.

Comment: Okay, I see, so that means I only can choose to shorten the title of ONE post per loop, right? Or is it possible to use various ids connecting with &? But I guess it would be better to be able to set one global maximum title lenght for all the posts in one loop.

Comment: Please put the semi-colon in that's missing - it prevents this answer from working. It would probably get a lot more upvotes if the code worked because it is a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [wp_trim_excerpt()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_trim_excerpt) function.

If you want need to specify chars limit, you should be able to use the [excerpt_length](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/37659/52791) filter.

```
<?php echo wp_trim_excerpt( get_the_title() ); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Wordpress API Solution**

If you want to trim english only or character only language, using `substring` would be the right way. However, if you want to trim language like **Chinese**, **Japanese** or the others, using substring might be awful, since they are using unicode to represent.

Using [wp_trim_words()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_trim_words) would be a simple and direct way to solve your problem.

```
wp_trim_words( $text, $num_words = 55, $more = null );
```

p.s. inspired by Leo Caseiro.

**CSS Only Solution**

If you want to find out how to trim the words dynamically especially in responsive design, you should use CSS like this:

```
.card-title {
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```