# apply_filters() and the_excerpt are giving unexpected results

Tags: excerpt, filters

I feel like I must be missing something pretty obvious, here, but I can't seem to get WordPress to cooperate.

I'm generating Facebook OG tags with a function. Everything works fine, except for the excerpt.

Since the deprecation of `get_the_excerpt($post->ID)`, is there another way to create an excerpt without having to create a whole new loop? It seems excessive to me.

My first instinct was to use `apply_filters()`:

```
$description = apply_filters('the_excerpt', get_post($post->ID)->post_content);
```

That gives me the full post, complete with HTML-formatted content. Okay, must be wrong. So I tried the next logical idea:

```
$description = apply_filters('get_the_excerpt', get_post($post->ID)->post_content);
```

No dice. Now there's no HTML, but it's still the full post (which is really confusing).

Okay, no problem. Let's skip all the fancy stuff and just go for the trimmed entry:

```
$description = wp_trim_excerpt(get_post($post->ID)->post_content);
```

No change.

So, my question is this: what the heck is going on? Is there something I'm missing, here?

I got into the WP core to find how `the_excerpt()` works, and it appears to be identical to my call:

```
/**
 * Display the post excerpt.
 *
 * @since 0.71
 * @uses apply_filters() Calls 'the_excerpt' hook on post excerpt.
 */
function the_excerpt() {
    echo apply_filters('the_excerpt', get_the_excerpt());
}
```

I have a few questions based on my findings:

1. Why isn't the filter applying as expected?
2. Is there a way to get the excerpt outside of the loop without creating a new loop?
3. Am I crazy?

Thanks in advance for having a look. I'm fairly stumped, here.

Comment: `get_the_excerpt()` isn't deprecated, just the extra param that used to be passed to it is no longer used.

Comment: Sorry, that's what I meant. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: You are crazy! . . . as am I lol

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Turns out the answer was in `wp_trim_excerpt()`.

It's defined in `wp-includes/functions.php:1879`:

```
/**
 * Generates an excerpt from the content, if needed.
 *
 * The excerpt word amount will be 55 words and if the amount is greater than
 * that, then the string ' [...]' will be appended to the excerpt. If the string
 * is less than 55 words, then the content will be returned as is.
 *
 * The 55 word limit can be modified by plugins/themes using the excerpt_length filter
 * The ' [...]' string can be modified by plugins/themes using the excerpt_more filter
 *
 * @since 1.5.0
 *
 * @param string $text Optional. The excerpt. If set to empty, an excerpt is generated.
 * @return string The excerpt.
 */
function wp_trim_excerpt($text = '') {
    $raw_excerpt = $text;
    if ( '' == $text ) {
        $text = get_the_content('');

        $text = strip_shortcodes( $text );

        $text = apply_filters('the_content', $text);
        $text = str_replace(']]>', ']]&gt;', $text);
        $excerpt_length = apply_filters('excerpt_length', 55);
        $excerpt_more = apply_filters('excerpt_more', ' ' . '[...]');
        $text = wp_trim_words( $text, $excerpt_length, $excerpt_more );
    }
    return apply_filters('wp_trim_excerpt', $text, $raw_excerpt);
}
```

So any text passed in doesn't get processed; **it only works if it's called with an empty parameter.**

To solve this, I added a quick filter to my theme that solves the problem:

```
/**
 * Allows for excerpt generation outside the loop.
 * 
 * @param string $text  The text to be trimmed
 * @return string       The trimmed text
 */
function rw_trim_excerpt( $text='' )
{
    $text = strip_shortcodes( $text );
    $text = apply_filters('the_content', $text);
    $text = str_replace(']]>', ']]&gt;', $text);
    $excerpt_length = apply_filters('excerpt_length', 55);
    $excerpt_more = apply_filters('excerpt_more', ' ' . '[...]');
    return wp_trim_words( $text, $excerpt_length, $excerpt_more );
}
add_filter('wp_trim_excerpt', 'rw_trim_excerpt');
```

It's somewhat redundant, but I like it better than opening new loops every time I want to generate an excerpt.

Comment: Ah, it was not clear to me you're looking for the text operation only (not fetching from DB).

Comment: No worries. I always fear I'm not making sense when I ask questions. I **was** pulling from the database, but I didn't want to open a whole 'nother loop since I have things like `get_the_title($post->ID)` available. The final line of code was `$description = wp_trim_excerpt(get_post($post->ID)->post_content);`

Comment: I feel really stupid asking this, but how do you call this new filter? I tried it as `$content = apply_filters( 'rw_trim_excerpt', $content );` and `$content = rw_trim_excerpt($content);`, but neither of these worked (former didn't trim the output and the later produced an error).

Comment: @QuantumDynamix This is designed to modify the `get_the_excerpt` handling to mimic `the_excerpt`, so you can call: `apply_filters('get_the_excerpt', $content);`.

Comment: phew! nice one from a wpress noob's point of view, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
   get_post($post->ID)->post_excerpt
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

See: [`get_post`<sup>*­Codex*</sup>](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post) for all available return members.

Comment: That returns blank if no excerpt was entered for the post. I need to mimic the actions of get_the_excerpt() (creating an excerpt if none exists).

Comment: Applying the filter won't do that, so you're asking the wrong question. No idea why you're looking for an excerpt if there isn't any. `get_the_excerpt()` does not mimic that, check the source, it's only accessing the member variable of `$post` which is `post_excerpt`. See also the codex link in the answer.

Comment: From the Codex entry on [`the_excerpt`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_excerpt): "it will display an automatic excerpt which refers to the first 55 words of the post's content." 

I'm looking to mimic that behavior outside of the loop.

Comment: Well create a second loop temporarily and query that file by it's id then probably for a quick solution. See *Secondary Loops* - http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts#Secondary_Loops

Comment: Thanks for the link. I knew I could set up an additional loop, but it seems like overkill. My solution was adding a filter. I see it as a little elbow grease now for a lot less code later.

Answer (score 0):

You can use my custom function to filte the content (it's from [NARGA Framework](http://www.narga.net/narga-core/))

- If the post has custom excerpt, display it instead the content
- Auto generate excerpt from the conten if the post hasn't custom cerpt
- Auto trim shortcode, HTML code, remove [...], add "Read More" text (translatable)

  ```
      /**
      * Auto generate excerpt from content if the post hasn't custom excerpt
      * @from NARGA Framework - http://www.narga.net/narga-core
      * @param $excerpt_lenght  The maximium words of excerpt generating from content
      * @coder: Nguyễn Đình Quân a.k.a Narga - http://www.narga.net
      **/  
      function narga_excerpts($content = false) {
      # If is the home page, an archive, or search results
      if(is_front_page() || is_archive() || is_search()) :
          global $post;
      $content = $post->post_excerpt;
      $content = strip_shortcodes($content);
      $content = str_replace(']]>', ']]&gt;', $content);
      $content = strip_tags($content);
      # If an excerpt is set in the Optional Excerpt box
      if($content) :
          $content = apply_filters('the_excerpt', $content);
      # If no excerpt is set
      else :
          $content = $post->post_content;
          $excerpt_length = 50;
          $words = explode(' ', $content, $excerpt_length + 1);
      if(count($words) > $excerpt_length) :
          array_pop($words);
          array_push($words, '...<p><a class="more-link" href="' . get_permalink() . '" title="' . the_title_attribute('echo=0') . '">  ' . __( 'Read more &#187;', 'narga' ) . ' </a></p>');
          $content = implode(' ', $words);
      endif;
      $content = '<p>' . $content . '</p>';
      endif;
      endif;
      # Make sure to return the content
      return $content;
      }
      // Add filter to the_content
      add_filter('the_content', 'narga_excerpts');
  ```